# Optimizing this mysql query to make use of my indexes if possible?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a mysql query that I thought should be using my indexes but still seems to be needing to scan alot of rows (I think).

Here is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DAY(broadcast_at) AS 'days' 
from v3211062009 
where month(broadcast_at) = 5 and 
year(broadcast_at) = 2012 
and deviceid = 337 order by days;
```

On my table I have an index setup on **broadcast_at, deviceid**.  However the results of a explain on this query looks like:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  v3211062009 ref indx_deviceid,indx_tracking_query   indx_tracking_query 4   const   **172958**  Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

I don't understand why it needs to look up so many of the rows.  The total amount of rows for this deviceid record is only **184085** so my query seems to be almost looking at all of them just to get the result set.  Is the index on broadcast_at not working.

I'm obviously doing something fundamentally wrong but can't figure it out.  Changing the order of the columns in my index didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think MySQL can take advantage of the index on `broadcast_at` if you use functions on that field.

How does it perform if you do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DAY(broadcast_at) AS 'days' 
from v3211062009 
where broadcast_at >= ('2012-05-01') AND
      broadcast_at < ('2012-06-01') 
and deviceid = 337 order by days;
```

Comment: Yes, and with an index on `(deviceid, broadcast_at)`, it would be much faster than the original query

Comment: @ypercube yes, indeed it should be.

Comment: @Alnitak o yes.  That seems to have done the trick and adjusted the rows to 11K lookup.  Much better thanks.